# error: reference to ‘_1’ is ambiguous

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the pcl_conversion functions in my ros2 subscriber node. Here is my code:

```
#include


#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "sensor_msgs/msg/point_cloud2.hpp"

#include "pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h"

using std::placeholders::_1;
#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS

class RobotVisioin : public rclcpp::Node
{
  public:
    RobotVisioin() : Node("robot_vision")
    {
      subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
      "/camera/depth/color/points", 10, std::bind(&RobotVisioin::topic_callback, this, _1));
    }

  private:
    void topic_callback(const sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg) const
    {
      RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg->data);
    }

    rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>::SharedPtr subscription_;
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<RobotVisioin>());
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

But i'm getting below error:

```
/home/ubuntu/turtlebot/src/robot_vision_cpp/src/robot_vision.cpp: In constructor ‘RobotVisioin::RobotVisioin()’:
/home/ubuntu/turtlebot/src/robot_vision_cpp/src/robot_vision.cpp:17:88: error: reference to ‘_1’ is ambiguous
   17 |       "/camera/depth/color/points", 10, std::bind(&RobotVisioin::topic_callback, this, _1));
      |                                                                                        ^~
In file included from /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp:2356,
                 from /usr/include/boost/bind.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2/slot.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2/connection.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2/signal.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/signals2.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/boost.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/file_io.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/io/pcd_io.h:44,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/pcl_conversions/pcl_conversions.h:72,
                 from /home/ubuntu/turtlebot/src/robot_vision_cpp/src/robot_vision.cpp:6:
/usr/include/boost/bind/placeholders.hpp:46:38: note: candidates are: ‘constexpr const boost::arg<1> boost::placeholders::_1’
   46 | BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR boost::arg<1> _1;
      |                                      ^~
In file included from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/context.hpp:19,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/contexts/default_context.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/executor.hpp:32,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/executors/multi_threaded_executor.hpp:25,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/executors.hpp:21,
                 from /opt/ros/foxy/include/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:146,
                 from /home/ubuntu/turtlebot/src/robot_vision_cpp/src/robot_vision.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9/functional:211:34: note:                 ‘const std::_Placeholder<1> std::placeholders::_1’
  211 |     extern const _Placeholder<1> _1;
      |                                  ^~
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/robot_vision_cpp.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/robot_vision_cpp.dir/src/robot_vision.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:78: CMakeFiles/robot_vision_cpp.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
```

Environment:
ros2 foxy, ubuntu 20.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379224/error:-reference-to-%E2%80%98_1%E2%80%99-is-ambiguous/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2021-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to move `#define BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` to before your `#include` statements.

When you include a header from a library that links against Boost (such as PCL), it checks to see if a `BOOST_BIND_NO_PLACEHOLDERS` macro exists. There is a condition in one of the Boost header files that optionally brings in Boost's placeholder types if this macro wasn't found. However, to disable this condition you need to define the macro before including any headers that bring in Boost headers.

---

Originally posted by [jschornak](https://answers.ros.org/users/37574/jschornak/) with karma: 340 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@jschornak gave the right solution for your specific issue, but I just wanted to add another suggestion that would prevent this: use lambdas instead of `std::bind` (or `boost::bind`). With that your subscription would look like:

```
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
  "/camera/depth/color/points",
  10,
  [this](sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg) { topic_callback(msg); }
);
```

Actually for small callbacks that allows you to implement the logic right there in place without the need of creating a separate method and pass pointers to it around:

```
subscription_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2>(
  "/camera/depth/color/points",
  10,
  [this](sensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2::SharedPtr msg) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "I heard: '%s'", msg->data);
  }
);
```

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2021-06-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3